# how to compare two json files and get the additional values or records copied to another file in python

Tags: python, json

Below are my two json file with same kind of records. As you can see it, in one file there are 3 items and in other file there are 5 items. I want those two additional items in another file.

Is there a way to compare two json files and get the additional values in the other file in python?

I found some questions related to comparing two files biut tey justgive the boolean value true or false as the result.
[Link to the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25851183/how-to-compare-two-json-objects-with-the-same-elements-in-a-different-order-equa/38722500)

> ===> file a.json

```
{
  "Count" : 3,
  "Items": [
      {
        "id"    : { "S"  : "1" },
        "name"  : { "S"  : "abc"},
        "email" : { "S"  : "abc@gmail.com"}
      },
        {
        "id"    : { "S"  : "2" },
        "name"  : { "S"  : "def"},
        "email" : { "S"  : "def@gmail.com"}
      },
      {
        "id"    : { "S"  : "3" },
        "name"  : { "S"  : "ghi"},
        "email" : { "S"  : "ghi@gmail.com"}
      }
    ],
  "ScannedCount" : 3
}
```

> ===> file b.json

```
{
  "Count" : 5,
  "Items": [
      {
        "id"    : { "S"  : "1" },
        "name"  : { "S"  : "abc"},
        "email" : { "S"  : "abc@gmail.com"}
      },
        {
        "id"    : { "S"  : "2" },
        "name"  : { "S"  : "def"},
        "email" : { "S"  : "def@gmail.com"}
      },
      {
        "id"    : { "S"  : "3" },
        "name"  : { "S"  : "ghi"},
        "email" : { "S"  : "ghi@gmail.com"}
      },
      {
         "id"    : { "S"  : "4" },
         "name"  : { "S"  : "jkl"},
         "email" : { "S"  : "jkl@gmail.com"}
      },
      {
         "id"    : { "S"  : "5" },
         "name"  : { "S"  : "mno"},
         "email" : { "S"  : "mno@gmail.com"}
      }
    ],
  "ScannedCount" : 5
}
```

Comment: Try writing some code.  Let us know what you come up with.

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is a way to diff JSON blobs. There's several packages out there for this. Here's a few:

- https://github.com/ZoomerAnalytics/jsondiff
- https://pypi.python.org/pypi/json-delta/
- https://github.com/seperman/deepdiff (you'll want to first parse the JSON into objects before using this one)

Answer (score 1):

Create objects from the file representation, compare the items, and then write output to a file.

```
import json

file_a = json.load(open("./a.json", "r"))
file_b = json.load(open("./b.json", "r"))

items_a = {value["id"]["S"]: value for value in file_a}
items_b = {value["id"]["S"]: value for value in file_b}

diff_keys = set(items_a) ^ set(items_b)
diff_items = {items_a[key] if items_a.has_key(key) else items_b[key] for key in diff_keys}

json.dumps(diff_items, open("file_diff.json", "w"))
```

Comment: It gives me following error `File "jsondiff.py", line 6, in <module>
    items_a = {value["id"]["S"]: value for value in file_a}
  File "jsondiff.py", line 6, in <dictcomp>
    items_a = {value["id"]["S"]: value for value in file_a}
TypeError: string indices must be integers`