# How to update db from json patch

Tags: python, json, postgresql, json-patch

I get a complex json every few hours. Part of it is a `Game` object with a list of `Player` objects that each `Player` has a list of `Training` object (each object has also other fields - ints, strings, list of strings etc.).
If the `Game` object doesn't exist in my Postgres db (I check by the `Game`'s id field), I insert the whole structure to the db, each object as its own table (a table for `Game`, a table for `Player` and a table for `Training`). Next time I get the json for this `Game`, it already exists in the db, so I want to update it. I get the old json, the updated json, and the json_patch.
I wanted to query the db, convert it to json, and apply the patch on that json. The problem is that the lists (of the players for example) are not sorted in the same way as the lists in the `updated_object` json. But I need to somehow work on the db because I need to have the primary keys of the objects so the ORM knows which objects to update.
What's the best way to approach it?

models:

```
class Game(Base):
    __tablename__ = "game"
    game_id: int = Column(INTEGER, primary_key=True,
                              server_default=Identity(always=True, start=1, increment=1, minvalue=1,
                                                      maxvalue=2147483647, cycle=False, cache=1),
                              autoincrement=True)
    unique_id: str = Column(TEXT, nullable=False)
    name: str = Column(TEXT, nullable=False)
    players = relationship('Player', back_populates='game')

class Player(Base):
    __tablename__ = "player"
    player_id: int = Column(INTEGER, primary_key=True,
                          server_default=Identity(always=True, start=1, increment=1, minvalue=1,
                                                  maxvalue=2147483647, cycle=False, cache=1),
                          autoincrement=True)
    unique_id: str = Column(TEXT, nullable=False)
    game_id: int = Column(INTEGER, ForeignKey('game.game_id'), nullable=False)
    name: str = Column(TEXT, nullable=False)
    birth_date = Column(DateTime, nullable=False)
    game = relationship('Game', back_populates='players')
    trainings = relationship('Training', back_populates='player')

class Training(Base):
    __tablename__ = "training"
    training_id: int = Column(INTEGER, primary_key=True,
                               server_default=Identity(always=True, start=1, increment=1, minvalue=1,
                                                       maxvalue=2147483647, cycle=False, cache=1),
                               autoincrement=True)
    unique_id: str = Column(TEXT, nullable=False)
    name: str = Column(TEXT, nullable=False)
    number_of_players: int = Column(INTEGER, nullable=False)
    player_id: int = Column(INTEGER, ForeignKey('player.player_id'), nullable=False)
    player = relationship('Player', back_populates='players')
```

json with updated data:

```
{"original_object":{"name":"Table Tennis","unique_id":"432","players":[{"unique_id":"793","name":"John","birth_date":"2023-10-28T00:10:56Z","trainings":[{"unique_id":"43","name":"Morning Session","number_of_players":3}, {"unique_id":"44","name":"Evening Session","number_of_players":2}]}]},"updated_object":{"name":"Table Tennis","unique_id":"432","players":[{"unique_id":"793","name":"John","birth_date":"2023-10-28T00:10:56Z","trainings":[{"unique_id":"43","name":"Morning Session","number_of_players":3}, {"unique_id":"44","name":"Evening Session","number_of_players":4}]}]},"json_patch":[{"op":"replace","path":"/players/0/trainings/1/numbre_of_players","value":4}],"timestamp":"2023-10-28T02:00:36Z"}
```

The json_patch updates the 'numbre_of_players' field of the second training to the value 4.

Code to add a new Game:

```
    Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine_sync)
        session = Session()
        session.begin()
        game = Game.from_dict(json['updated_object'])
        existing_game = session.query(Game).filter_by(unique_id=game.id).first()
    if not existing_game:
        session.add(game)
        session.commit()
```

But if the `Game` does already exists in the db, I'm not sure what I should do.

Comment: Do `Player` objects have a unique ID? If so, you can compare them the same way you compare `Game` objects. If not, you can define a sorting method, then compare the `Game` objects like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25851183/how-to-compare-two-json-objects-with-the-same-elements-in-a-different-order-equal).

Comment: @lucs100 They do have a unique ID. I use the 'jsonpatch' python library. It gets the patch and apply it on the json. I wanted to avoid manually go through the path of the patch and see what object is being updated, then go to the db and update it.

Comment: Can you elaborate on why/where the different order is a problem? If you're inserting each player as a row into a `Player` table, it doesn't matter what order you insert them in. If you're then updating those `Player` rows, it again doesn't matter what physical order they are in in that table, or what order they come in the update batch (unless you have multiple updates for the same player in one batch). Please describe the process where this order is important and how its inconsistency breaks things.

Comment: If you wish to be able to retrieve the `Player` rows in the same order they came in the json structure, you'll have to add an explicit `order by` clause that reflects how they were ordered. If there's no clear rule, you'll need to add a key with an ordinal number indicating what their position in that array was. Also, I'm wondering why you're trying to add this process side-by-side with an ORM, which typically should be able to handle inserts and updates like that on its own, automatically, reflecting creation and changes to entities and their relationships in the db

Comment: @Zegarek I don't know what the sort order in the updated_object will be anyway. Not sure what you're suggesting. How should I update the db according to the json_patch?

Comment: @RonyTesler I'm merely trying to understand or guess what you're trying to achieve and what your problem actually is. **1)** Why are you trying to update the DB using `json_patch`, while at the same time having an ORM that should be able to handle all of this on its own? **2)** Can you share the code you're using now to populate the `Game`, `Training` and `Player` tables, along with some sample/mock data? **3)** Can you share the code that tries to update the tables and show how it's failing when the array order changes?

Comment: @Zegarek how the ORM can handle that? I'll update the question with code examples, thanks.

Comment: @RonyTesler specifics depend on the ORM, but as the name suggests, it's meant for Object Relational Mapping - translating objects in your app to relations (tables) on your database, which includes links between (and hierarchies of) these objects. Here are some examples in SQLAlchemy: [saving linked objects](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/tutorial/orm_related_objects.html#persisting-and-loading-relationships), [updating an object](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/tutorial/orm_data_manipulation.html#updating-orm-objects-using-the-unit-of-work-pattern).

Comment: @Zegarek I meant - how do I update the db according to the json_patch that's not aware of the ORM. I updated the question and added some code.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a task for [`sqlalchemy.orm.Session.merge()`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/session_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.Session.merge). You're looking at 3 possible states of the same `Game`:

1. one in the database,
2. one in your session,
3. another one, wherever you're getting this updated state from

You want to update/overwrite whatever the first two states are, assuming the third one is true.

```python
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine_sync)
session = Session()
session.begin()
game = Game.from_dict(json['updated_object'])
game = session.merge(game)
session.commit()
```

No need to check if it's already in you session and/or in the db, because `merge()` checks this automatically, and if it doesn't find a matching `Game`, it adds it as a new one. From the doc:

> [`Session.merge()`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/session_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.Session.merge) examines the primary key attributes of the source instance, and attempts to reconcile it with an instance of the same primary key in the session. If not found locally, it attempts to load the object from the database based on primary key, and if none can be located, creates a new instance. The state of each attribute on the source instance is then copied to the target instance. The resulting target instance is then returned by the method; the original source instance is left unmodified, and un-associated with the `Session` if not already.

Remember to set up your [cascades](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/cascades.html#unitofwork-cascades) accordingly, to deal with all objects that might be related to it.

Comment: The problem is that it uses the primary key for comparing the objects. I have a postgres primary key (game_id for example) and a unique_id which is unique, but it's not the primary key. I could remove the game_id primary key and use the unique_id, but actually the unique_id is unique only within the company that created the game, so the primary key would be 'unique_id + company_id' and I think merge doesn't support that. Also, removing the game_id and other existing primary keys would be a too much big change for now.

Comment: **1.** `Primary key` implies `unique not null` - it's also unique by design. I don't see why that's a problem and why you're looking for other unique (combination of) columns. Also, your model definition doesn't specify `unique_id` is unique. **2.** As a side-note, it's entirely possible to set up a multi-column primary key and instruct [SQLAlchemy](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/faq/ormconfiguration.html) to use them as such. Also in [PostgreSQL doc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-PRIMARY-KEYS).

Comment: Your model definition doesn't specify `unique_id` is actually `unique`, even [partially](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-partial.html), or [to](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-UNIQUE-CONSTRAINTS)get[her](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/constraints.html#unique-constraint) with company (that I don't see). Those constraints must be clearly defined for the ORM or DB to be able to use them accordingly.

Comment: Ok, I understood why that's a problem, just noticing that `json_patch` doesn't see the `game_id`, `player_id`, `trainind_id` columns. Can not you make them available to it? Alternatively, you could add a `company_id` column to make it a multi-column primary key together with `unique_id` instead. But if you could change that, I don't see why you couldn't just as well be able to make the current pk column visible to `json_patch`. Also, if `unique_id` isn't truly unique, your current code can find a different game from a different company, with the same `unique_id` and wrongly assume it's not new

Comment: I get the json_patch from a third party, I can't change it. I simplified the code for this SO question. The real code queries by unique_id and company_id.